# Asp.net MVC Progress bar while application starting

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html

How can I show loading Progress bar in Asp.net MVC5 , while application starting the Home Index page

I know how to show and hide progress bar but my issue is what event I need to capture to start the progressbar when page init and hide progress bar when page loaded fully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jquery for that purpose but you should not use progress bar for whole page.It should be used with **ASP.NET MVC** views especially the partial views.
The following useful article can help

[How Do I Display a Progress Bar?](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_ui_mvc_progressbar.ashx)

Regards.

Comment: I know how to show and hide progress bar but my issue is what event I need to capture to start the progressbar when page init and hide progress bar when page loaded fully.

Comment: Did you take a look to the article that I mentioned in my answer

Comment: Yes , I have gone through but  I need _layout.cshtml will display progress bar  while loading page without any interaction on controller

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your concern is not strictly progress bar, but how to implement this before landing page. So my answer is that the only way (without using silverlight or flash) would be create some 'almost blank' landing page and then, when this site will be loaded you have to make ajax call for content of this site (during this process you can display progress bar). It makes impression that progress bar is displayed before landing page. I cannot see any other solution.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PACE JQuery plugin](http://freebiesbug.com/code-stuff/pace-js-progress-bars-websites/) and [here its get started tutorial](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/)